# ¿Cómo se llama a una acción de un controlador de ASP.NET MVC desde ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un proyecto en ASP.NET y tengo pensando iniciar una migración progresiva del proyecto a ASP.NET MVC, instalé por Nuget las referencias de MVC y cree un área para ahí trabajar.

Ahora la duda es:

- ¿Es suficiente con instalar por el Nuget las referencias de MVC?
- ¿Cómo se llama a una acción de un controlador de ASP.NET MVC desde ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Es suficiente con instalar con Nuget las referencias de MVC?

No, tienes que realizar varias modificaciones en tu proyecto web. Para realizar un "híbrido" puedes leer:

- [Integrating ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC](http://rachelappel.com/integrating-aspnet-web-forms-and-aspnetmvc/)
- [ASP.NET MVC alongside Web Forms in the same web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7288840/457643)

> ¿Cómo se llama a una acción de un controlador de ASP.NET MVC desde ASP.NET?

La forma como se redirige de una a otra página en ASP.NET es usando el método [`HttpResponse.Redirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx). Para poder invocar a una acción de un controlador solo sería realizar, por ejemplo:

**Desde code behind:**

```
Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Accion", "Controlador", new { Area = "Area", id = 1}));
```

**Desde el formulario:**

```
<%= new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Action("Accion", "Controlador", new { Area = "Area", id = 1}) %>
```

Recuerda que con `Action` se busca generar una Url de la forma `RecepcionCta/Index?Area=Area&id=1`.

---

**Referencia:**

- [Método UrlHelper.Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [Método HttpResponse.Redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Gracias @Davlio, pero por ejemplo desde la una lista en una pagina aspx quedaría asi?  <li> Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "RecepcionCta", new { Area = "MVC"})); </li>

Comment: @jeissoni22 acabo de actualizar mi respuesta

Comment: la instruccion <%= new UrlHelper().Action("Accion", "Controlador", new { Area = "Area", id = 1}) %> me lanza un erro. El valor no puede ser nulo. Nombre del parámetro: routeCollection

Comment: @jeissoni22 En todo caso, quizás puedas usar `<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/RecepcionCta/Index?Area=MVC") %>`